# Composer require alternative: extensionA or extensionB

Tags: php, composer-php

I am using apc user cache functions in my library package (https://packagist.org/packages/hazardland/db) but as you know:

**Till PHP 5.5 there was estension ext_apc** http://pecl.php.net/package/apc (user cache + opcache)

**And from php 5.5 there is ext_apcu** http://pecl.php.net/package/APCu which only implements user cache functions and not opcache.

So in my composer.json I need **to require one of these two** exstensions: ext_apc or ext_apcu whichever user has. Is it possible to setup such kind of extension dependency ?

If I require only ext_apc I am loosing php 5.5.x users but if I require only ext_apcu I am loosing  php 5.4.x users.

Update after research:

So there are 2 directives in composer **provide** and **replace** but they cant help because I need that ext-apcu was provided by ext-apc and as ext-*-s are hardcoded virtual packages in composer, at least composer team needs to change them ? *(I even can't find in virtual package list ext-apc or ext-apcu on packagist.org.)*

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/751

Comment: Checked - no solution yet... : P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loaded **only ext-apcu** extension and after:

`composer show --platform`

Returns this:

`ext-apc             4.0.7    The apc PHP extension
ext-apcu            4.0.7    The apcu PHP extension`

So just **require ext-apc** deals with both cases.